# reload a document in a webbrowser control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, navigation, webbrowser-control

I have a vb.net form with multiple webbrowser controls. on one webbrowser4 I need to lunch this macro that pull some data from a report every minute with a timer 
Webbrowser4.navigate("c:\macr.r2w")

webbrowser.refresh doesn't reload the macro, I got an error with dispose, I can't open more than one IE instance(memory overload), I tried to navigate to `about:blank` first and then the webbrowser, it didn't help. How can I reload the same macro on the same webbrowser every minute?

I appreciate your help.

---

I tried this

```
 WebBrowser4.Navigate("C:\marco.r2w" + "?refreshToken=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
```

but again it opens many instant of my macro

Comment: How you are using `refresh` ? Have you looked here: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts4tye44.aspx) for `WebBrowserRefreshOption`. Which framework is currently you are using ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I'm using WebBrowser4.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely). framework 4

Comment: I tried this but again it open many IE instant